# Is replacing names with pronouns common in multiple points of view narration?

Tags: narrator

In Hanya Yanagihara’s “Little Life”, the narration toggles between the four protagonists. When it focuses on either of them, his name is usually mentioned once and then consecutively omitted and replaced by the pronouns “he”, “his”, and “him”, thus giving the impression that the person is (right next to) the narrator. It works wonderfully in this novel (even though sometimes these pronouns clash with pronouns referring to other male characters, but then they are sometimes disamibugated e.g. “his” is replaced with “his own”).

Is this convention common in English-language literature?

Edit:

An excerpt:

> Andy had been looking down at **his** ankle as *he* spoke, using tweezers to pick out shreds of dead flesh from a wound **he**’d developed, when *he* suddenly froze, and even without seeing Andy’s face, **he** could tell *he* was chagrined. “I’m sorry, Jude,” *he* said, looking up, still cupping **his** foot in *his* hand. “I’m sorry I can’t tell you differently.” And when **he** couldn’t answer, *he* sighed. “You’re upset.”

As I understand, the instances of **he** in bold refer to Jude, the instances in *italic* refer to Andy. Yikes!

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but is it possible for you to add a sample passage from that book, for clarity?

Comment: From reading sample pages from Google Books, there is something unusual here that you have pointed out. The paragraphs have characters interacting in continuously changing pairs or in relation to the group (usually designated as they or them). It resembles a square dance. The word "he" switches who it refers to again and again. I find that if I read it quickly, my native feel for English lets it make sense, but if I stop to work out who each "he" is specifically referring to, it takes longer than I expected or than I think is usual.  Ex: pages 11 and 14.

Comment: I've [seen this done](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2188/17) in one English novel, but I thought it worked very badly there.

Comment: Also, I am having trouble thinking of third person novels with three or more roughly equal protagonists. It may be rare to have a similar set of characters.

Comment: “Little Life” gradually focuses on one of the four (I think, I’m only half through the novel).

Comment: I added an excerpt I found interesting.